# Spring MVC rendering 404 due to wrong view

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I'm debugging a controller method in Spring MVC that should return a view, but I'm getting a 404 page.

**Error**

```
HTTP Status 404 
/WEB-INF/views/responsive/pages/company/myCompanyCreatePurchaseOrderPage.jsp
```

The view is actually located in

```
/WEB-INF/views/pages/company/myCompanyCreatePurchaseOrderPage.jsp
```

**Code**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/admin/getPoNumbers", produces = "application/json")
protected String getPurchaseOrdersFromSettings(@RequestParam(value = "uid")
final String uid, final Model model, final HttpServletRequest request, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
  // unrelated code omitted

  return "pages/company/myCompanyCreatePurchaseOrderPage";
}
```

Where does this prefix get set?

Comment: Check your *view resolver* configuration.

Comment: can you able to post your view resolver configuration related code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InternalResourceViewResolver bean on your web.xml or applicationContext.xml

Sample

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass">
        <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView</value>
    </property>
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```